# How do I access properties from page in ContentPlaceholder in my MasterPage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have following environment:

- masterpage with a contentPlacholder
- multiple pages which use this masterpage and implement a base-class (`fooPage`)
- `fooPage` has a certain property (`fooProperty`)

Now i want to do something like

```
public partial class FooMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    // this is originally from the designer-file
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder;

    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var fooPageInstance = this.ContentPlaceHolder as fooPage;
        var fooPropertyInstance = fooPageInstance.fooProperty;
        // TODO do something with the property
    }
}
```

Obviously this is not going to work - but how can I achieve this?

I know the alternative: call a method from the masterPage in the contentPage with `fooProperty` as a parameter - but i would like to rather have a pull-system in this case...

Comment: @abatishchev: thanks for the edit, but it was kinda unneeded to remove the namespace from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`... i include namespaces for clarity purposes! btw. why not give `page` an uppercase `P`?? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class FooMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    // this is originally from the designer-file
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder ContentPlaceHolder;

    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var fooPageInstance = this.ContentPlaceHolder.BindingContainer as FooPage;
        var fooPropertyInstance = fooPageInstance.fooProperty;
        // TODO do something with the property
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MasterType` attribute on master page.

See :   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx

Comment: -, and how is this related to the question??

Comment: @Andreas: When you use a @ MasterType directive, such as the one in the example, you can reference members on the master page as in the following example:

CompanyName.Text = Master.CompanyName;

Comment: is i've mentioned in my question: i do not want to use push systems! the problem is, i want to access properties of the contentPage from the masterPage (opposite direction!)