# Updating a literal control on a master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages, postback, master-detail

In my child page i have an imageButton, which is surrounded by the UpdatePanel.
When the user clicks on the image button a record is removed from my database.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRemove" /></Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
                <layouttemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </layouttemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnRemove" runat="server" CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>'/></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

In my master page i have literal control which displays the records for the current user (something like `Records: 10`)

The RecordsCount control is updated on the page Load event of the MasterPage

```
 Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      RecordsCount.Text = GetRecordsCount()
 End Sub
```

So here are my questions

1. How can i update the `RecordsCount` control? 
   I mean i use postbacks for removing records from the database. And currently the RecordsCount control will be updated if the user hits the Refresh button of the Internet browser.
2. How could i apply the [Jquery Highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) on the `RecordsCount` control when the user clicks on the `btnRemove` button on the child-page?

**UPDATE:** Well the first question is solved by using javascript

Comment: did you mean apply class `highlight` on control `RecordsCount `

Comment: @TheSuperTramp Sorry... the Jquery Highlight

Comment: just as an input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956066/how-do-i-access-properties-from-page-in-contentplaceholder-in-my-masterpage... this is how I retrieve properties of the master page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it sounds like i have had a happy end!

The RecordsCount control is updated with javascript while the (Attribute Ends With Selector) Jquery was applied successfully via this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283837/multiple-jquery-selectors)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[id$="btnFavorite"]').click(function () { $('#Favorite').effect('highlight', { color: '#AAAAAA' }, 3000); }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't the way to do it. Check out Chris his answer

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a badly done layout.

The master page should NOT be responsible for displaying data page specific data.  Instead it is there to simply provide the layout and "holes" with various content panels so the pages can plug in data / controls.

I'd rip that out of the master page and add a new content panel to allow the pages to display the data.  Then in your page, add the record count or whatever else you want.

Comment: Could you please remove your answer? This will stop users from reading my question. I hope you understand.

Comment: @Chocol8: You're kidding right?  People look at questions based on title, and subject matter.  They'll continue reading based on the complexity of the question itself.  Just because there is an answer on question, whether you like the answer or not, isn't really going to make a difference