# Multiple jquery Selectors

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors, client, client-side

Thanks to [karim79](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70393/karim79) i am able to click on the `ImageButton` and apply the Jquery highlight effect to a different `div`

```
$("#btnFavorite").click(function() {
    // selector for element to highlight
    $("#theDiv").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Now i would like to extend the question as follows.

I add the `ImageButtons` to the webpage dynamically, and i would like to apply the effect on the `div` for every `ImageButton` click.

```
     <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
        <layouttemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </layouttemplate>
        <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnFavorite" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Favorite.png"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

What should i do in that case? By using `ItemDataBound` of the listview and adding attributes
like

`btnFavorite.Attributes.Add("onmouseclick", "doSomething")` or what?

I am totally lost!

Comment: apply a CssClass and use $('.your-class') to add behavior to several items. ID=unique class=multi ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a more generic selector like this...

```
$("input[type='image']").click(function(){
    $(".. related div selector ..").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

I don't know the relationship between the `div` and the `input` so I can't assume what the selector is but if you post the relationship or explain it we can help you write a more accurate selector.

It should be worth noting that if you are dynamically added the `ImageButton`s to the page after the DOM has loaded and not on the server side then you would likely want to use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method for attaching events...

```
$("input[type='image']").live('click', function(){
    $(".. related div selector ..").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The 'input[id$="btnFavorite"]' (Attribute Ends With Selector) did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an attribute named `class` to the `ImageButtons` you want to have this effect maker function, and value it with a name, for example **effectMaker**. Then call the same function, but change the selector to

```
$(".effectMaker").click(function() {
    // selector for element to highlight
    $("#theDiv").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

With the `.` selector followed by a *stringValue*, you reference every element that has a class valued with that *stringValue*.

Comment: but note that would be less performant (which may or may not matter). If you must use classes, see if you can be a bit more specific with the parents ala $("#idOfParent .effectMaker")

Comment: Yeah, but the user seems a novice about jQuery and DOM elements. I thought it was better to not overfilling his head with too many information.

Comment: Finally someone who understands! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some say the delegate function is better than the live function:

http://test.kingdesk.com/jquery/bind_live_delegate.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you, but what I've done is this:

```
$("#<%= ListView1.ClientID %>").find(".ImageButtonTarget").click(function() {
   ..
});
```

I give my button control a unique class to find it with, and parse the entire list view in bulk.  I'm not sure if there is one or many divs, but if the div is in the listview row, you can also use a combination of parents and find to grab that from the ListView row too.

This also keeps the scoping to within the ListVIew; the selector doesn't have to parse the entire page to find the image buttons, only within the list.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This will apply effect() on every input of type 'image' within the 'theDiv' container:

```
$('#theDiv').find('input[type="image"]').effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
```

Or, this will apply it to 'theDiv' on every input type image click:

```
$('input[type="image"]').click(function() {
  $('#theDiv').effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
});
```

Not sure which one you're trying to do.